# learning torah for deceased person - is all reward to the deceased?

Tags: torah-study, death, reward-punishment

There is a custom to learn torah (especially mishnayos) for a deceased person. Does all the torah study reward go to the deceased person or does some torah study reward also go to the person learning? (not asking for the reward of kindness, just for torah study)

please source

Comment: I always assumed that the deceased doesnt get the reward of Torah learning,rather they get the merit for the person learning Torah.

Comment: I think the concept is that the learning is in the "merit" of the deceased. I.e., we acknowledge that the deceased taught us proper behavior so that we can learn Torah and we are the ones that receive the reward. I don't think that others receive a reward for what you do, whether the other is alive or dead. I.e., if I learn Torah, even if you are alive, how would you receive the reward if you do nothing? I think this principle applies to the deceased, as well.

Comment: perhaps connected: See the Bartenura on Avot 2:2, "And you, I consider your reward".  -- http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37946&pgnum=318
 -- there he gives 3 explanations of what it means, and I think they would apply to this as well.  -- Also, like @DanF said, I think the point is that if not for this person we would not be learning, so that person receives some credit as well.

Comment: Also, see a discussion about this whole topic from a rationalist view by R' Natan Slifkin here: http://www.zootorah.com/RationalistJudaism/What%20Can%20One%20Do%20For%20Someone%20Who%20Has%20Passed%20Away.pdf -- with a parenthetical followup here: http://www.rationalistjudaism.com/2017/04/missing-you-dad.html

Comment: @Menachem i heard slifkin is considered a bad source from the gedolim

Comment: There's a lot that he says that I disagree with, but he brings sources, so you can look up the sources yourself

Comment: Good luck finding a good source. Your soul came down here to do its job, after which you go to _afterlife_ and get rewarded for *your* actions. End of story. You cannot eat nor do Mitzvoth for other people. (You do get eternal reward for the _consequences_ of *your* actions - e.g. somebody learns Torah 100 years after you pass on because you taught him how to read.) As the Gemara says multiple times אין כפרה למתים -  there is no way to create atonement for somebody no longer alive. Sad, but true. Do your Mitzvoth now.

Answer (score 2):

I was told by Harav Chaim  Kanievsky, that Learning Torah or doing a good deed for the merit of someone else does not take away from the merit of the person who is learning or doing the deed.

Comment: you heard this directly from him? or read in his name?

Comment: @m.r. I  heard it directly from him.

Comment: @m.r. I responded in a private email.